# Create single list/column from multiple tables in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I want to combine the values in two tables into a single list - what function does this?

[image: Sample tables and output]

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy [chris-neilsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/445425/chris-neilsen):

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,B2:C3)&"</s><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,E2:F3)&"</s></t>","//s[not(preceding::*=.)]")
```

*Note: this addresses the original [pre-revision] Q which stipulated unique values should be output, to reproduce all values incl. duplicates this function becomes:* `FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,B2:C3)&"</s><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,E2:F3)&"</s></t>","//s")`