# Union function to append two lists in Excel (not Office 365)

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I have two lists (variable length) in Excel (1, 2 resp.) and wish to find the union of these:

[image: Union]

My research yields numerous solutions / questions to this effect, however, they either focus on Office 365, VB, Lambdas, PowerQuery variations - they do not proivde a function fit for Excel 2010 etc.:

**Requirements/research:**

- No Office 365 requirement (so no FilterXML, let, choose, etc. etc. - per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70892421/appending-two-lists-in-excel), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67731682/create-single-list-column-from-multiple-tables-in-excel), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66343922/how-to-extract-unique-items-from-multiple-column))
- Am not interested in VB (trivial) / PowerQuery (ditto - i.e. simple 'insert/data/append 2 or more queries)
- Am not interested in Lambda variations (per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69837142/using-unique-with-non-adjecent-columns-on-different-sheets))
- Duplicates are fine

**Progress**

Have been contemplating an offset function that picks up values in the 2nd list once those in the first list are exhausted in an array function -- but am a litte lost otherwise (and don't want to restrict anyone in scope of functions that may be avail. in this regard).

Can someone assist me in finding a function per above pls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using INDEX/MATCH:

```
=IF(ROW(A1)>COUNTA($B$4:$B$6),INDEX($D$4:$D$7,ROW(A1)-COUNTA($B$4:$B$6)),INDEX($B$4:$B$6,ROW(A1)))
```

Put that in F4 and copy down.

[image]

Comment: nice one! thanks (ideally this is in array format - even though I didn't specify this preference - will give it a go and let you know if I don't come right if that's OK)..